# Is the right adjoint to presheaf direct image interesting?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map. It induces on presheaves a classical adjunction inverse image $\dashv$ direct image. However, the direct image functor has a further right adjoint, defined by the limit formula for right Kan extensions
$$U\mapsto \varprojlim _{U\supset f^{−1}(V)}GV$$
where $G$ is a presheaf on $Y$ and the colimit is over opens $V\subset Y$ satisfying the condition in the formula.

On a formal level, sheafifying this adjoint does not give something obviously satisfying since sheafification is left adjoint, so there are no adjunctions to compose.

Question 1. Is the right adjoint of the presheaf direct image hiding in plain sight?

Question 2. When life is good, the derived *proper* direct image admits a right adjoint which captures duality. Is it in any way related to the right adjoint of presheaf direct image?

Comment: Question 2 seems interesting but I don’t understand Question 1. It’s a right Kan extension, which is a well known thing. There’s certainly no better known thing that it also is.

Comment: Got it. I think not, but there may well be something to be said.

Comment: It's a bit too glib to think that right adjoints preserve everything characterized by limit conditions. A sheaf on $X$ is a functor $O_X^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set}$ preserving certain limits. If we have a right adjoint with domain $\mathrm{Set}$, composition with that will preserve sheaves, just like with group objects. But we are looking at a right adjoint $[O_X^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set}]\to [O_Y^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set}]$, which is quite different. If $X=*$ and $Y$ admits some nontrivial open cover of the whole space, and we consider the right adjoint $p_R$ to direct image for...

Comment: $p:Y\to *$, then $p_R$ sends $F$ to the presheaf $U\mapsto \lim_{U\supset p^{-1}(V)}F(V)$.. If $U\neq Y$ then this limit is just over $F(\emptyset)=*$, so we end up with $p_R(F)(Y)=F(*)$ while $p_R(F)(U)=*$ for $U\subsetneq Y$, a presheaf whose sheafification is the terminal object.

Comment: I would say delete them. It might not be a bad idea to just ask a fresh question, removing (1), if we're agreed that it wasn't clear what to do with that.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I think I'll edit it and ask to migrate. Let's delete the comments :)